# host name can't be null using Grails Spring Websocket Plugin

Tags: tomcat, grails, stomp

i'm developing a simple web application using the spring websocket plugin for grails.

While in local everything works well, deploying the application on a testing server online, i receive those execptions:

Chrome console:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

Tomcat Console:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkHost(InetSocketAddress.java:149)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:216)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-02-07 19:18:26,382 [http-apr-8081-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /innovaserver/stomp/611/hkjlpvdk/websocket
hostname can't be null. Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://109.168.108.18:8081/innovaserver/stomp/611/hkjlpvdk/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkHost(InetSocketAddress.java:149)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:216)
... 6 more
```

I'm using Tomcat 7.55, Ubuntu Server

Comment: Solved! I've to add a mapping in the hosts file, mapping the host name with the private IP of the machine in the data center.

Comment: You should add this comment as an answer and mark as accepted.  Worked for me as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I've to add a mapping in the hosts file, mapping the host name with the private IP of the machine in the data center.